# Simultaneously record screen and preview camera in a web app works bad on Chrome/macOS setup

Tags: javascript, html, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder, get-display-media

The goal is to preview a stream of the computer's web camera in a html video element and at the same time record audio and the Chrome tab showing another video and the preview using the MediaRecorder API, navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia and navigator.mediaDevice.getUserMedia.

The implementation runs well using Chrome and Ubuntu/Windows setup but it becomes laggy when it runs on macOS. Javascript code is provided below. Any ideas on why the implementation works bad specifically on macOS?

I have tried to change codecs from vp9 to vp8, lower the framerate to 24 and the resolution is already reduced. If I go lower the quality gets to bad.

I have tried reducing the quality of the streams and recording without any performance increase on macOS.

```
    export default function VideoRecord(props) {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
​
    useEffect(() => {
        async function onLoad() {
            try {
                //some code
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        setIsLoading(false);
    }
​
    onLoad();
    }, [props.match.params.id]);
​
    var mediaRecorder;
    var recordedChunks = [];
    var videoStream;
    var cameraStream;
    var combinedStream;
    var BLOB;
    var cameraElem;
    var videoElem;
​
    $(function() {
        cameraElem = document.querySelector('#camera');
        videoElem = document.querySelector('#video');
    })
​
    var videoMediaOptions = {
        video: {
            width: 720,
            height: 480,
            aspectRatio: 1920/1080,
            cursor: "never",
            frameRate: 30
        },
        audio: false
    };
​
    var cameraMediaOptions = {
        video: {
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        },
        audio: true
    }
​
    async function startCapture() {
        try {
            videoStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(videoMediaOptions);
            cameraStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(cameraMediaOptions);
            cameraElem.srcObject = cameraStream;
            startRec();
​
        } catch(err) {
            console.error("Error: " + err);
        }
    }
​
    function handleDataAvailable(event) {
        if (event.data.size > 0) {
            recordedChunks.push(event.data);
            createBlob();
        }
    }
​
    function startRec () {
        var options = { mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp9" };
        combinedStream = new MediaStream([...cameraStream.getAudioTracks(), ...videoStream.getTracks()]);
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(combinedStream, options);
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
        mediaRecorder.start();
    }
​
    function createBlob() {
        BLOB = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
            type: "video/webm"
        });
​
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(BLOB);
​
        videoElem.srcObject = null;
        videoElem.src = url;
        videoElem.muted = false;
    }
​
    function stopCapture() {
        let cameraTracks = cameraStream.getTracks();
        cameraTracks.forEach(cameraTracks => cameraTracks.stop());
​
        let tracks = videoStream.getTracks();
        tracks.forEach(track => track.stop());
        mediaRecorder.stop();
    }
​
    function renderPage(){
        return (
            <div className="videoWrapper">
                <video preload="auto" id="video"></video>
                <video id="camera" autoPlay muted></video>
                <Button id="startBtn" onClick={startCapture}>Start</Button>
                <Button id="stopBtn" onClick={stopCapture}>Stop</Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
​
    return (
        <div id="videoRecordID" className="VideoRecord">
            {!isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>}
            {!isLoading && renderPage()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: MacOS's webcam and screen capture stuff is a little fiddly compared to Win or Linux. Try reducing the frame rate and / or resolution for getDisplayMedia(). Try capturing only audio with getUserMedia(), Keep in mind that using getDisplayMedia() does a pure screen-scrape operation. It must capture the raw image data from the screen and run it through the coder (vp9 in your case).

Comment: And , try vp8 in place of vp9.

Comment: I have tried reducing frame rate and resolution, but if I go lower on the resolution the video quality gets to bad for my use case. Do you know if there is any alternative to getDisplayMedia() ? I need to capture the screen at the same time as the camera and audio.